# Typescript allowing `Object.entries` when targeting es2015

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I'm trying to compile my typescript code into javascript compatible with es2015, so I set my target in tsconfig.json to "es2015". I use `Object.entries` in my code, but AFAIK that was added on 2017, so I would expect `tsc` to either replace it with a polyfill or complain about it. But it just compiles fine and keeps `Object.entries` as is.

I know that typescript is seeing the target because it does replace the `??` operator (which it doesn't when I target es2020). But I want it to also either warn me or fail when I use features that aren't available, since I could be using other features that I'm not aware are not available on the version I'm targeting. It's hard to memorize and keep in mind which features I can and cannot use when I'm targeting es2015.

I also tried adding "ES2015" to "lib" to see if it'd ignore newer versions, but it didn't do anything. When I control-click `Object.entries` to go to definition it takes me to `lib.es2017.object.d.ts`. Is there any setting I can use to tell typescript to ignore every lib after 2015?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.  [It complains about `Object.entries()` in the TS Playground when targeting ES2015](https://tsplay.dev/wgZO0W).  Maybe your configuration isn't what you think it is?  Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @jcalz You're right, it works on a fresh new project, so I must be doing something wrong, I'll report back if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, the solution was to uninstall `ts-node` from the project. No idea how is doing it but it's breaking `tsc` just by being inside `node_modules`.